# Sharing printers with computers and not users in Win Server 2012

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012

I have a LAN network with 120 users, not so big. They're all splited in differents rooms, which some have a network printer. In AD, I can easily find the printers and setting their sharing configuration to the users. Also, I installed all printer's drivers on this server.

However, some users often need to print stuff in other rooms, but when they do it, their stuff is printed in their original room, instead of the closest printer to them. So I need to assing the computer his using (which will be loged in their account) to the closest printer, so if the user is at another room, he can manage to print documents next to him.

I've tried to make a group with the machines of that room only (Ex.: group ROOM-12) and assing  the printer to it, but the user which was logged in the computer, member of that group, couldn't find the printer.

I'm new to Win Server stuff. I'm using WS 2012. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using group policy preferences with item-level targeting.

In your GPO that is linked to your user's OU, drill down to Preferences > Control Panel Settings > Printers, right-click and create a new printer item.  Open the Common tab and tick Item-level Targeting > Targeting > New Item > OU > Computer is in OU.  This will let you assign different printers to your users depending on the OU of the computer they log into.  Obviously it will require that you have computer OUs that reflect your rooms.

[image]